# The largest root of $-3x^3+24x^2+6x-9=0$

Tags: polynomials, roots

Since the polynomial has three irrational roots, I don't know how to solve the equation with familiar ways to solve the similar question. Could anyone answer the question?

Comment: Did you try dividing through by $-3$?

Comment: The only question I see is "Could anyone answer the question?" If I answered "No" I would be contradicting myself. So I'll have to answer "Yes".

Comment: If you divide by 3 through, we get $-x^3 + 8x^2 + 2x - 3 = -x(x^2 - 8x - 2) - 3 = 0$. Could you go from here?

Comment: If you use rational root theorem, you will know that this polynomial doesn't have any rational root but three irrational roots.

Comment: Thanks for your whimsical answer.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, this kind of polynomial is called Casus irreducibilis. Though the discriminant is positive, the roots are all irrational and expressed with radicals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used Mathematica to obtain the roots using the [cubic formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_formula_for_roots), which I then simplified with the `ComplexExpand` function.  The root which is largest in absolute value is

$$
x_\max = \frac{8}{3}+\frac{2}{3} \sqrt{70} \cos\left[\frac{1}{3} \arctan\left(\frac{9 \sqrt{2351}}{1087}\right)\right] \approx 8.19930.
$$

The other two roots are

$$
x_\pm = \frac{8}{3}-\frac{1}{3} \sqrt{70} \cos\left[\frac{1}{3} \arctan\left(\frac{9 \sqrt{2351}}{1087}\right)\right]\pm\sqrt{\frac{70}{3}} \sin\left[\frac{1}{3} \arctan\left(\frac{9 \sqrt{2351}}{1087}\right)\right],
$$

which are approximately

$$
x_+ \approx 0.513388
$$

and

$$
x_- \approx -0.712687.
$$

Comment: Thanks for your effort. But they seem different from the result of WolframAlpha 
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-3x%5E3%2B24x%5E2%2B6x-9
My approximation also gave me the similar result as Wolfram. Do you know why?

Comment: @User, whoops, I must've typed in the wrong polynomial.  I just updated the answer with the correct roots.

Answer (score 2):

The roots of cubic polynomials are obtained in a way which is similar to what is done with quadratic polynomials. I suggest you look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function).
The basic idea is to transform a $x^3 + b x^2 + c x + d =0$ to the so-called depressed cubic which, after a simple change of variable, write $t^3 + p x + q = 0$. Then, the sign of $(4 p^3 + 27 q^2)$ tells the nature of the roots and its value allows to compute these roots whatever the could be (real or complex).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I accidentally found this article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis and I could confirm that your method is the ONLY way to solve this kind of polynomial.